# Opening connection in OleDb

Tags: vb.net, database-connection, connection-string, oledb

I am getting an "Unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDB.OleDbException" occured in system.data.dll" error

```
 Dim MDBConnString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Folder\F1\Loader.mdb"
 Dim con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(MDBConnString)
 Dim cmd As New OledbCommand
 con.Open() 'on this line
```

Comment: The code should work, is there any "Additional Info" displayed indicating where the error is i.e. i recreated the error if the database did not exist (wrong spelling or filepath) and the "Additional Info" was "Could not find file path..."

Comment: wrap the con.Open inside a Try Catch block and display the exception. From the error, I'm assuming this is in your form load and the exception is being buried.

Answer (score 0):

save your database file in Access2003 and use this code

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Conn" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\YourDatabaseName.mdb;"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: You can add it to app.config file.